# 301 Redirect Simple Products to Grouped Parent in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am combining some simple products in our catalog to grouped products.  I need to create 301 redirects from the current simple product pages to the new grouped product page.

Here is an example of what I have:

1. Products a, b, and c are similar simple products, each with
   their own url.
2. Grouped Product z has a, b and c associated to it.
3. Visibility for a, b, and c are changed to "not visible individually."
4. Visiting the old link for product c results in a "404 Not Found" error.

I want step 4 to result in a "301 Moved Permanently" with the grouped product url.  I know I can change the entries in the URL Rewrites list manually, but I am looking for a more automated approach.

Can anybody help point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the file app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php with:

```
protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
        $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        $params = new Varien_Object();
        $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);

        $parentIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped')->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
        if(isset($parentIds[0])){
          $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentIds[0]);
          die($parent->getProductUrl());
        }

        return Mage::helper('catalog/product')->initProduct($productId, $this, $params);
    }
```

I would expect that to kill any simple product page view, but it doesn't.  It seems like the product controller is not being called for products set as not visible.  Is that correct?

**UPDATE 2:**

If I modify the "core" file instead of the "local" version, this works.  Any ideas on why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Try to rewrite controller according to [this site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller), but I don`t think you have to rewrite controller. I suggest you rewrite helper.

Comment: Your answer consists mostly of a link. While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I think this may be a good direction, but I'm not clear that it will allow me to redirect simple product requests to a grouped parent if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If your code work from core maybe you did not extend with success product controller, check to see if your module is loaded, also check to see if somehow other module/extension not extend same controller as the one you want to extend.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: 
1.) if your products which are part of the grouped don't have visibility set as "Not Visible Individually"(simple or downloadable), you can follow this tutorial which uses observer pattern and it is working.[magento-grouped-product-redirect-tutorial](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-grouped-product-redirect-tutorial/)
The bottom line is :

use this event:

```
<events>
            <catalog_controller_product_init_after>
                <observers>
                    <company_catalog>
                        <class>company_catalog/observer</class>
                        <method>redirectGrouped</method>
                    </company_catalog>
                </observers>
            </catalog_controller_product_init_after>
        </events>
```

and that code inside your Observer:

```
public function redirectGrouped(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $groupedTypeInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');
        $parentIds = $groupedTypeInstance->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());

        foreach ($parentIds as $parentId) {
            $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);
            if ($parent
                && $parent instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
                && $parent->getTypeId() == 'grouped'
            ) {
                $redirect = Mage::getStoreConfig(
                    'catalog/grouped_options/redirect_enabled',
                    Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                );
                if ($redirect) {
                    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($parent->getProductUrl());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

2.) if you have the products with visibility "Not Visible Individually" as I do you will notice that the above solution doesn't work. Unfortunately Magento checks the visibility right before the event we use and returns false.

So what we can do is:
rewrite `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php`
and on function  `public function initProduct($productId, $controller, $params = null)`

right after the check : `if (!$this->canShow($product))`

add use the same code as above as it is working correctly.

```
$groupedTypeInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_grouped');
            $parentIds = $groupedTypeInstance->getParentIdsByChild($product->getId());

            foreach ($parentIds as $parentId) {
                $parent = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentId);
                if ($parent
                    && $parent instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
                    && $parent->getTypeId() == 'grouped'
                ) {
                    $redirect = Mage::getStoreConfig(
                        'catalog/grouped_options/redirect_enabled',
                        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                    );
                    if ($redirect) {
                        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($parent->getProductUrl());
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```